# Blender 3.0 assignes None to the object when choosing it in the Boolean modifier

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers

Nowaday I'm trying to learn the Blender scripting and already have a trouble in my Blender 3.0.
The problem is when I choose object in the Boolean modifier there is None assigned to the proper class field in the corresponding Info panel's Python line. Why?

[image]

Comment: This looks like a bug in the eyedropper tool. It does that in 2.93 as well. Selecting from the dropdown gives the expected result.

Comment: @Ron Jensen It's sadly. Is there way to report this bug to the developers? Although I think we will see this bug (or maybe some another) in the version 4.0 and higher...))

Comment: To file a bug, use the Help Menu from the top bar and select "Report Bug".  I can't find it now, but based on a previous report I suspect this will be closed as "works as designed".

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a bug. It's just that only clicking on the eyedropper is logged (and at that point the object field is cleared), the only eventual bug here is that clicking on the object is not logged. Not even with `debug_wm` set to `True`, in which case only `bpy.ops.ui.eyedropper_id()` is logged.